# How do I download a Maharashtra Village Boundary layer .?

Tags: geospatial

How to Download Maharashtra Village Boundary.?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, the first Google search result for "Maharashtra Village Boundary" yields a geospatial data for download: https://projects.datameet.org/indian_village_boundaries/mh/

Answer (score 1):

Usually remote area of small villages are hard to come by. You could install Google Earth, then:

1. Search the area
2. Select the Polygon Tool
3. Digitize the area yourself

[image]

This would be a good way to start a project. You could then download a desktop GIS software such as [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) or any other GIS Desktop software for further work.

Comment: google earth is not open source